# Problema al desplegar ruby on rails en plesk e instalación gema racc

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps, plesk

Cuando intento correr el `bundle install` en plesk para desplegar una aplicación `ruby on rails` me da el siguiente fallo, primero pensé que sería un choque de versiones, ya que en local uso `ruby 2.6.6` y en la documentación de plesk vi como que aún no estaba soportado, y en el selector de versión de ruby, de plesk no aparece, con lo que cambié el .ruby_version a la version 2.5.5 que si acepta plesk, y tambien cambié la versión de ruby en mi entorno local. tengo el repositorio del proyecto conectado por github (pero supongo que esto no debería influir).

He intentado ir corrigiendo todolo que he podido ir entendiendo de los errores, pero uno que se sugiere en las  imagenes que van a continuación es `gem install racc -v 1.5.2 --source https://rubygems.org` pero cuando lo intento me aborta la instalación y sale como que no encuetra la gema para instalarla.

Ya no se me ocurre que mas puedo hacer, y luego de intentarlo durante todo el finde, recurro a vosotros a ver si podeis aportar un poco de luz!

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Using rake 13.0.3
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using i18n 1.8.9
Using minitest 5.14.3
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using activesupport 6.1.3
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Fetching racc 1.5.2
Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
[DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being 
remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in 
future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local path 
'vendor/bundle'`, and stop using this flag
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory:/var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/racc-1.5.2/ext/racc/cparse
/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210301-263180-1qqi823.rb
extconf.rb
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in 
`try_do':
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:541:in
`try_link0'
from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:559:in
`try_link'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:771:in
`try_func'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1058:in
`block in have_func'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:948:in
`block in checking_for'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in
`block (2 levels) in postpone'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
`open'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in
`block in postpone'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in
`open'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:346:in
`postpone'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:947:in
`checking_for'    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1057:in
`have_func'    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'
 To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which 
 can be found here: /var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log
 extconf failed, exit code 1
 Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/racc-1.5.2
 for inspection.
 Results logged to /var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/racc-1.5.2/gem_make.out
 An error occurred while installing racc (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
 succeeds before bundling.
 In Gemfile:
 rails was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
 actioncable was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
 actionpack was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
 actionview was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
 rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
 nokogiri was resolved to 1.11.1, which depends on
 racc
```

el resultado del mkmf.log es el siguiente:

```
"x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest -I/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/builder/bootstrap/ext-ruby.git=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--enable-new-dtags  -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lruby-static  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
#include "ruby.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  return 0;
}
/* end */
```

y el del gem_make.out

```
current directory: /var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/racc-1.5.2/ext/racc/cparse
/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210301-263692-yjgbrl.rb 
extconf.rb
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME) /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': 
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:559:in `try_link'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:771:in `try_func'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1058:in `block in have_func'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:948:in `block in checking_for'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:947:in `checking_for'
    from /opt/plesk/ruby/2.5.5/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1057:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which 
can be found here: /var/www/vhosts/lagramoladisco.com/picmaton/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

la verdad es que no entiendo apenas que debería configurar en relación de lo que sacan estos archivos ni como solucionarlo.

toda ayuda es binebenida!

Comment: Primero que nada, recuerda que siempre es mejor que agregues el texto de tu error en vez de un pantallazo. Hazte la vida más simple a ti y para quienes puedan ayudarte... eres un usuario antiguo, deberías saberlo ya. Respecto a tu error, lo más seguro es que te falte alguna librería de sistema para poder compilar la gema, revisa ese archivo `mkmg.log` generado y agrega las últimas líneas del log a tu pregunta para saber cuál es esa librería.

Comment: @AlterLagos entono el mea culpa y edito las imagenes a código,gracias por tomarte las molestias, me pongo a buscar el mkmg.log y cuando lo encuentre posteo resultados

Comment: @AlterLagos esta respuesta me sirvio de mucha ayuda, gracias!! a partir de ahi, tuve que instalar y configurar algunas cosas mas (passenger,sqlite3...) pero me resolviste los problemas, ahora ya si hace el bundle install sin fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave está en el mensaje `You have to install development tools first.` que indica que debes instalar las librerías base de desarrollo.
Para distros basadas en Debian (Ubuntu, etc), prueba con:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

En caso que estés en MacOS, se necesita las librerías de desarrollo de Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```